# Transferring MySQL DB To New Server

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to transfer Data from my old MySql Server to my new server,                       I have tried using SQL Dumper, but i keeping getting `Error 500` The tables are a mess half been MyISAM and the other half been InnoDB and the server is on its last legs to be honest.

I am thinking of using `iframes` and `GET` requests to transfer the data (example below). If anyone has any better ideas it would be much appreciated.

The table i am transferring has 36 Million records and i have tested it and a rough calculation it will take over to months to transfer all the records. 
I knows the method below is probably the most inefficient way to do it but i can't think of any other way to do it.

```
     $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM nu_list $limit");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

    print "<iframe src="http://mynewsite.com/add.php?row1=$row[1]&row2=$row[2]&row3=$row[3]" 
frameborder="0" scrolling="no" WIDTH="1" HEIGHT="1">\n";  } 


        $nxt = $_GET["pageno"] + 1;

        if($nxt < $lastpage) {
        print "<BODY>
        <script type=\"text/javascript\">
        <!--
        window.location = \"/ripw3.php?pageno=$nxt&lastpage=$lastpage\"
        //-->
        </script>
        </BODY>
        </HTML>\n";
```

Comment: iframes and PHP code are the very last thing I'd think of to migrate a database.  Use `mysqldump` to export!

Comment: If it doesn't work out with mysqldump (well, it should, but anyway...), there are other tools, for example, SQLyog.

Comment: Tried MySql Dump just getting error 500

Comment: Then you're not using `mysqldump`.

Comment: __YOU SHOULD BE DOING IT FROM THE COMMAND LINE.__

Comment: You do have access to the command line, right?

Comment: Yes i have access to the command line if i try an do a MySql Dump the server freezes for 5 mins then shows error 500

Comment: Then youre not actually using the command line. The command line has nothing to do with HTTP or the HTTP status code 500. You should `ssh` into the server, run `mysqldump` and then `gzip` the resulting data file, then use `scp` to transfer it to the new server, gunzip it and load it into the mysql instance.

Answer (score 2):

If you have access to the server and can shell to it, you should use mysql dump to dump a copy of the database. Then transfer that sql file to the new server and import it.

This site provides a solid [mysql dump import / export tutorial](http://www.mydigitallife.info/how-to-backup-and-restore-export-and-import-mysql-databases-tutorial/).

If you're hell-bent on getting this done with php, there are some folks who have written scripts to [backup mysql with php](http://davidwalsh.name/backup-mysql-database-php). The basic idea is to show all tables, loop through them and describe each table in order to build create table statements, and then select the data in each table in small chunks and manually building insert statements. That's an awful pain in comparison to the dump though.

If you're on a shared host you probably can't use mysql dump, which might explain your error 500. If you're on a shared host though, you probably could download a copy of your database from your control panel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MySQL Workbench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) to do a complete export of your databases and `pt-show-grants` from [Percona Tookit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit/) to export users and privileges.